# Not able to open a https link in JSF

Tags: jsf, url, hyperlink

When I try to open the https URL in jsf using window.open, I could not open it. How can this be done?

Code:

```
<h:commandLink id="downloadLink2" target="_blank" tabindex="3"
    onclick="clickLink();" ajax="false"
    style="border:0px;text-decoration: none;" title="#{doc2.name}">
          <h:outputText value="#{doc2.path}" title="#{doc2.path}" />
</h:commandLink>

<script>
    /* <![CDATA[ */
    function clickLink(){
    alert('test');
    window.open('https://sso.csx.com/idc/idcplgIdcService=
       GET_FILE&dID=2502493&dDocName=P2484813');
    }/* ]]> */
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

`<h:commandLink/>` is a **POST** request. For navigation, use a **GET** request component such as `<h:outputLink/>`. JavaScript code can be embedded in the component using onClick attribute.

```
<h:outputLink onclick="window.open('https://sso.csx.com/idc/idcplgIdcService=GET_FILE&amp;dID=2502493&amp;dDocName=P2484813');" value="#">
      <h:outputText value="Open Window"/>
</h:outputLink>
```

PS: Note that `&` is escaped with `&amp ;`

Comment: When I do this, I get the following  error :  Error Traced[line: 706] The reference to entity "dID" must end with the ';' delimiter.

Comment: <h:outputLink id="downloadLink1" target="_blank" 
          onclick="window.open('#{doc1.path}');" 
          value="#{doc1.path}">
      <h:outputText value="#{doc1.name}" title="#{doc1.name}" />
        </h:outputLink>